# valid schema for company and suppliers and clients?

Tags: sql, database-schema

I am having a problem in modeling relation between a company and suppliers and clients. Basically in my system the supplier and the client are companies too so I made this schema:

```
table.company:
id
name
//other fields

table.company_suppliers:
company_id FK table.company.id
supplier_id FK table.company.id

table.company_clients:
company_id FK table.company.id
client_id FK table.company.id
```

Is this ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use only one table which will contains all the company and a bit field (called by instance Supplier )which will tell you which are are suppliers too.

```
Company

Id
Name
IsSupplier (bit)
Fk_IdSupplier  --it will relate this supplier to a company on the same table
```

Or you can create a junction table (many to many)

```
Company 

    Id
    Name
    IsSupplier (bit)

CompanySupplier

fk_IdCompany
fk_IdSupplier
```

Answer (score 0):

Your basic insight is right--you don't want unrelated tables of clients and suppliers. But you have too many ID numbers.

```
create table companies (
  company_id integer primary key,
  company_name varchar(35) not null
);

create table suppliers (
  supplier_id integer primary key references companies (company_id)
  -- Other supplier columns go here.
);

create table clients (
  client_id integer primary key references companies (company_id)
  -- Other client columns go here.
);
```

If you're using MySQL, you'll need to adjust the syntax a little. MySQL doesn't support all the standard SQL syntax for declaring primary keys and foreign keys.